# Multiple tables vs role-based authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, authorization, access-control, abac

**Question**

What is the use case for deciding to switch from role-based authorization to having separate tables for users?  Is there a design pattern or convention that recommends when one approach is cleaner to implement/maintain than the other?

**Details**

I'm building a Rails 4.2+ application, but this question is not strictly Ruby/Rails, although if there is a convention for Rails I would like to hear what it is.

In this application, a client enters and submits data but also needs the ability to see the status of their submission as well as add additional info (docs, clarifications, etc...).  That's all a client does: submit data, check the status of their submissions, and get email notifications.  They can be associated to multiple accounts if the client decides to enter a submission to multiple accounts.

Staff, on the other hand, actually process the client's submission and are associated to a single account. It is also theoretically possible that staff could become a client and have their own submission.

The "view layer" for each type of user is very different, with each performing very different roles.  This can be addressed with both multiple tables as well as with role-based.

However, the data for each type of user will be somewhat different.

For instance, a client enters personal information that goes into the "clients" table as well as several associated tables, and the client will be treated like a "contact" in the system.

Staff, on the other hand, will not need to have the same level of personal information in the system since that information is only necessary to process the submission.  As mentioned earlier, though, a staff could potentially become a client, which if I did role-based authorization, would be a nightmare to implement.

Staff will also have additional authentication requirements, such as 2-step authentication (clients will not need this).

As I look at this application, what I'm really seeing are 2 distinct applications operating together: the client side and the staff side.

Most of the research and questions I've looked at seem to continually counsel using a single users table and implementing roles for authorization.  This means I would have a bunch of conditionals all over the application, though.  Most other developers even on SO (I came across several similar questions in my research) seem to look down upon multiple tables for users.

Answer (score 1):

### What you need to do is

1. define your information model
2. define your authorization requirements
3. externalize / decouple the authorization requirements from the business logic.

Regarding 3. have a look at ABAC ([abac](/questions/tagged/abac)) - attribute-based access control. It's the access control model NIST recommends when what you need cannot be be handled through RBAC ([NIST ABAC project page](http://csrc.nist.gov/projects/abac/)).

### Let's have a look at your use case:

- users can be clients or staff or even both
- users can belong to multiple accounts
- accounts contain submissions
- submissions have creators

### Your authorization requirements

- A client can edit a submission they created
- A staff member can process submissions if the submission belongs to an account the staff member is associated with
- a client can view all the submissions for the accounts they belong to

### Reworking your requirements 'ABAC' style

- a client can view all the submissions for the accounts they belong to

becomes

- A user with the role == client can do the action == view on an object of type == submission if and only if submission.account is in user.assignedAccounts

### Implementing ABAC

There are a few different ways to implement ABAC. One such way is to use XACML, the eXtensible Access Control Markup Language ([xacml](/questions/tagged/xacml)). XACML works well for many different languages (Java, .NET, Ruby...) There are several implementations of XACML such as Axiomatics or SunXACML.

In Ruby, you also have an authorization gem called [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan). If you are looking for a fully-integrated Ruby-based approach, then CanCanCan is the easiest option you have.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to rails, so I'm not sure if there should be any special considerations when designing for rails. This problem does not seems to be associated with authentication, but with authorization

So your system have following functions,

- Client

  1. Profile with a lot of info
  2. Submissions view
  3. submissions / status
- Staff

  1. Process submissions
  2. View pending / processed submissions

So if you have a client role and staff role it's not hard, and if a user has client profile the user can see the appropriate functions, and same goes for the staff. You can design tables as you want, you can have 3 tables, user, staff and client where based on the role(s) appropriate tables are populated for a user

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at multi tenancy. Here is a description and overview of possible schemes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx.

I believe in your case, because you also need a view over all users data, one database with a schema per user should work. This way all tables have the same name, just another schema.